# How to open Terminal.app and execute a script on MacOS X Catalina using Java?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, macos-catalina

I have a java app that at one point needs to open up MacOS X's Terminal, with the Terminal then executing a script.  The Terminal needs to be visible during this process.  This needs to be using Java 8.   The following code works fine under any tested MacOS X versions previous to Catalina (10.15).  However, with Catalina, the Terminal does not open up, and certainly doesn't execute a script. In the code below, the path to the script is contained within scriptPath.

```
String[] pathArray = new String[] {"open",  "-a","/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app",  scriptPath};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathArray);
```

Is this another example of Catalina's increased security?  Is there a way around this?

Comment: If it's a security thing then maybe a file in /var/log got changed.

Comment: Do you need to open the CLI tool or could you simply create a GUI with the output from the process?

Comment: It's a security thing. `String[] pathArray = { "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", "java -version" };` shows `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app": error=13, Permission denied` - your "open" and "-a" hide the issue. BTW, I'm on 10.14.6 (so, your problems didn't start with Catalina).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you left off "open", Terminal.app is a directory?. David are you sure the app still has the same naming convention?

Comment: Thanks, @ElliottFrisch!  It works fine on 10.4.6 - at least on my machine.  I've been using this code for over a decade, and it never failed before Catalina.  I suspect the lack of the "open" that @matt pointed out might be your issue.

Comment: @Jason - I don't really need to open a CLI tool - but it was an easy way for users to see that what were happening.  I could pull out the output from the process, but that would take more time and I was hoping for a quick bug fix for my Catalina users.

Comment: @DavidMaddison It's actually really easy to get the IO from the process. If you wan't, I can provide an answer with just that.

Comment: @DavidMaddison It doesn't work with your original version on my machine. **But** I use iTerm2 usually. Just started Terminal.app manually and that works, but your code does not (on my machine). No errors or messages, it just appears to successfully do nothing.